# Realiza la validación pero no muestra el valor

Tags: php, html

estoy probando este código y funciona a medias; Funciona porque si realiza la validación pero no muestra el valor como tal del $fila["username"]

```
$user_a_p =  $sql = "select * from as_users"; 
    $ds = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds)){
    
      echo $fila['email'] ==  $userInfo['email'] ? '<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input name="compradores" type="checkbox" id="compradores" value="$fila["username"]"> $fila["username"]" </input></label>' : ''; 
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus ayudas

Comment: No ves el valor porque los estas concatenado mal. Por otro lado, si solo necesitas el usuario cuyo email es igual a `$userInfo['email']` ¿por que en tu consulta no buscas puntualmente eso?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en que no estás concatenando correctamente la variable con el resto del texto que estás pasando.

```php
    echo '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="compradores" type="checkbox" id="compradores" value="' . $fila["username"] . '">' . $fila["username"] . '</input></label>';
```

Cuando utilizas `echo` en php, este se comporta de manera distinta según el tipo de comillas que le pongas. https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

Si quieres utilizar comillas dentro de comillas, procura de que las que utilizas dentro, sean distintas a las que has utilizado fuera. En este caso usaremos comillas simples `' '`, dentro de comillas dobles `" "`

**Otra manera con la que puedes hacerlo**

```php
    echo "<label class='checkbox-inline'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='compradores'  id='compradores'>";
    echo $fila["username"]."</label>";
```

En este caso lo que hacemos es crear el `<label>`, dentro añadir el `<input>`, y en vez de asignarle a él el valor y volver a cerrar el `</label>`, le asignamos el valor deseado. En este caso `$fila["username"]`